# From error 1109 to error 1242 MySQL

Tags: mysql, case, mysql-error-1242

I'm using a procedure to calculate the length of user 'hiatus' (aka contingencies) from the program in our system. It runs after a procedure that determines user status depending on whether they are completing their daily treatment and to what extent.

The purpose of this procedure is to log the length of a user's contingency, by adding a row to a table with the following schema:

`id_contingency int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  id_user int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  date_start date DEFAULT NULL,
  program_day int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  date_end date DEFAULT NULL,
  total_days int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  latest_tf_id archer(255) DEFAULT NULL`

I considered adding this as a trigger on the update of the user_status table, but I can't risk an error preventing that table from updating. So, this procedure first closes contingencies that were previously open, when the user first entered the hiatus, but has now resumed the program, and it later opens new contingencies for users who have now started a hiatus in their treatment for the first time. It then remains open until they resume the program, and calculates how long they were on hiatus for.

This was my original procedure, and it returned error 1109 (unknown table tbl_user_status) :

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=CURRENT_USER PROCEDURE `proc_cont_calc`
NO SQL 
BEGIN

#CLOSE OPEN CONTINGENCIES FIRST  or d0 > d1
CASE 
    WHEN tbl_user_status.d4 = 1 AND tbl_user_status.d2 > 0 AND tbl_user_status.user_status = 'seguimiento' THEN 
        UPDATE tbl_user_contingency, tbl_user_status SET 
        tbl_user_contingency.date_end = CURRENT_DATE,
        tbl_user_contingency.total_days = DATEDIFF(tbl_user_contingency.date_start, tbl_user_contingency.date_end),
        tbl_user_contingency.updated_by = 'proc_cont.close'
        WHERE tbl_user_contingency.date_end = '' AND tbl_user_contingency.id_smoker = tbl_user_status.id_smoker LIMIT 1;
#OPEN NEW CONTINGENCIES
    WHEN tbl_user_status.d5 = 1 AND tbl_user_status.d4 = 0 AND tbl_user_status.user_status = 'contingencia' THEN
        INSERT INTO tbl_user_contingency (id_smoker, roadmap_day, date_start, latest_tf_id, updated_by) SELECT 
        id_smoker, roadmap_day, CURRENT_DATE, latest_tf_id, 'proc_cont.open' FROM tbl_user_status;
END CASE;
END$$ 
DELIMITER;
```

So I tried this (amongst other things):

```
CASE 
    WHEN (SELECT d4 FROM tbl_user_status) = 1 AND (SELECT d2 FROM tbl_user_status) > 0 AND (SELECT user_status FROM tbl_user_status) = 'seguimiento' THEN 
        UPDATE tbl_user_contingency, tbl_user_status SET 
        tbl_user_contingency.date_end = CURRENT_DATE,
        tbl_user_contingency.total_days = DATEDIFF(tbl_user_contingency.date_start, tbl_user_contingency.date_end),
        tbl_user_contingency.updated_by = 'proc_cont.close'
        WHERE tbl_user_contingency.id_smoker = tbl_user_status.id_smoker LIMIT 1;
#OPEN NEW CONTINGENCIES
    WHEN (SELECT d5 FROM tbl_user_status) = 1 AND (SELECT d4 FROM tbl_user_status) = 0 AND (SELECT user_status FROM tbl_user_status) = 'contingencia' THEN
        INSERT INTO tbl_user_contingency (id_smoker, roadmap_day, date_start, latest_tf_id, updated_by) SELECT 
        id_smoker, roadmap_day, CURRENT_DATE, latest_tf_id, 'proc_cont.open' FROM tbl_user_status;
END CASE;
```

And now I'm getting error 1242 returning multiple rows.

How can I get this procedure to run properly? Thanks!

UPDATE - I tried @P.Salmon's suggestion to simply update the rows, but not all the fields were filling out, or the update overruns previous contingencies.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The case statement seems unnecessary here just move the conditions to where clauses for example

```
UPDATE tbl_user_contingency join tbl_user_status on tbl_user_contingency.id_smoker = tbl_user_status.id_smoker 
    SET 
        tbl_user_contingency.date_end = CURRENT_DATE,
        tbl_user_contingency.total_days = DATEDIFF(tbl_user_contingency.date_start, tbl_user_contingency.date_end),
        tbl_user_contingency.updated_by = 'proc_cont.close'
WHERE tbl_user_contingency.date_end = '' AND
           tbl_user_status.d4 = 1 AND tbl_user_status.d2 > 0 AND tbl_user_status.user_status = 'seguimiento'
;

INSERT INTO tbl_user_contingency (id_smoker, roadmap_day, date_start, latest_tf_id, updated_by) 
SELECT 
        id_smoker, roadmap_day, CURRENT_DATE, latest_tf_id, 'proc_cont.open' 
FROM tbl_user_status
where tbl_user_status.d5 = 1 AND tbl_user_status.d4 = 0 AND tbl_user_status.user_status = 'contingencia'
;
```

You could improve your question and get thereby a better response if you describe what it is you are trying to do instead of having us guess by reverse engineering two non working code segments, by adding your table definitions, sample data and expected output as text to your question. BTW I hope you have a mechanism that will stop this thing doing stuff more than once.

Comment: Thanks @P.Salmon. I added edited the question to add the info on what the procedure is for, and I'm going to give your idea a shot.

Comment: Thanks @P.Salmon. It worked to get rid of the errors, of course, but it still doesn't open and close contingencies.